# Why react state binding not work when i render children not in props

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and found that child is not re-render properly by it's parent's state if it's not render from props.

```
this.children = props.children

return (
    <div>
        {this.children}
    </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/yj7vmn571x

Comment: Why do you want to write `this.children` instead of just `props.children`?

Comment: The snippet doesn't reflect the demo. The snippet suggests that you assign `this.children` in `render` but you forgot to mention that you actually do this once in constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to clone props.children for additional classNames. Properly i should do it by React.Children.map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
    this.children = this.props.children;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
        {this.children}
 </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With every state change new props will be passed to container
 but as this.children is not updated because constructor is called only once in lifetime but this.props.children is updated everytime.
If you wanna do this do this move it inside render,though not recommended.
https://codesandbox.io/s/524qm53014

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that, you want to add extra stuff to your component's children

use

React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])

and

React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  
  
  render() {
    
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
       return React.cloneElement(child, {
         className : 'cool'
       });
    });
    return (
      <div>{children}</div>
    );
  }
  
}

function App (props) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.app-wrapper'))
```

```css
.cool {
  background : tomato;
  color:white;
  padding : 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```